# Laravel 5.2 set wrong status codes in response for POST requests

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, get, http-status

I setup fresh laravel 5.2 project and in my `routes.php` file I have:

```
Route::get('/happy', function () {
    abort(403,'Unauthorized - its OK :)');
});

Route::post('/sad', function () {
    abort(403,'Unauthorized - its not OK :(');
});
```

Here are screenshots from postman:
[image]
[image]

For GET i have good response status code = 403, but for POST i get bad response status code = 200. How to make POST status codes right(=403)?
I use body-raw POST mehtod for sending json (not in this exaplme).

Answer (score 1):

Instead  of using raw, use form data to send post value, then you will get an exact result

Answer (score 0):

May be just do what is writen on Postman response: set 'always_populate__raw_post_data' to -1 in php.ini

Comment: this is problably bug in PHP 5.6. Even if don't use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in php scripts - the php will trow that error when POST body is raw (and application/json).